# How do I copy a file from a directory to another directory with the same name with a modified filename in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a drive on D:\ that has folders and files laid out like this
"ThisFolder\ThisFolder09.mp3" and "OtherFolder\OtherFolder13.mp3"

I need to copy them to E:\ that has folders like this (I am using the previous names here)
"ThisFolder\ThisFolder.mp3" and "OtherFolder\OtherFolder.mp3"

The numbers at the end will never be more than 2 digits, they are the week number; as in there are about 52 weeks in one year, like week 2 would be the 2nd week of the year.

Using ThisFolder as an example, I need to copy "D:\ThisFolder\ThisFolder09.mp3" to "E:\ThisFolder\ThisFolder.mp3"

I thought about using Copy-Item for copying, but I couldn’t find how to remove the week number from the file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Santiago's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75072111/45375) provides the crucial pointer with respect to modifying the file *name* as desired.

To address the aspect of **wanting to keep the *directory path* the same as in the input file, but on a *different drive***, use the following - **assuming the target directories on the target drive already exist**:

```bash
$sourceDrive = 'D:'
$destDrive = 'E:'

Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -LiteralPath "$sourceDrive\" -Filter *.mp3 |                            #" (to fix broken syntax highlighting)
  Copy-Item -Destination {
    $_.FullName -replace "^$sourceDrive", $destDrive -replace '\d+(?=\.mp3$)' 
  } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

**If you need to create the target directories on the target drive *on demand*,** more work is needed:

```bash
$sourceDrive = 'D:'
$destDrive = 'E:'

Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -LiteralPath "$sourceDrive\" -Filter *.mp3 |                            #" (to fix broken syntax highlighting)
  Copy-Item -Destination {
    $destDir = (New-Item -ErrorAction Stop -Force -Type Directory ($_.DirectoryName -replace "^$sourceDrive", $destDrive).FullName
    Join-Path $destDir ($_.BaseName -replace '\d+$' + $_.Extension) 
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `-replace '\d+$'` to remove the ending digits from the files `.BaseName` (the file name without its extension). For example:

```
$source      = 'D:\ThisFolder'
$destination = 'E:\ThisFolder'

Get-ChildItem $source -File -Filter *.mp3 | Copy-Item  -Destination {
    Join-Path $destination (($_.BaseName -replace '\d+$') + $_.Extension)
}
```

Comment: It is not always going to be “ThisFolder” D:\ and E:\ have a lot of folders with different names, but the same scheme “D:\ThisName\ThisName06.mp3” -> “E:\ThisName\ThisName.mp3” and “D:\OtherName\OtherName24.mp3” -> “E:\OtherName\OtherName.mp3

Comment: @JohnB17 then repeat this process each folder to copy ?

Comment: I would like it to be scalable so it will pick up all of the folders and do this without having to manually define them.

Comment: @JohnB17 then do it? your question demonstrated a poor attempt at solving the problem and I will not code a solution for you. I am simply demonstrating how you can solve a fraction of the problem